# What is the equation of a line fitting a log-log model computed in R?

Tags: r, regression, linear-model, logarithm, function

I am currently stuck, wanting to extract a line function from my fitted line on my log-log model.

```
#model
modelMV <- lm(log(Outputs3$MaxVel3SD) ~ log(Outputs3$Mu))
hmMV <- exp(predict(modelMV,list(Mu=Outputs3$Mu))
```

```
#line
lines(Outputs3$Mu, hmMV, lwd=2)
```

Notice that I use exp(model) in hmMV.

For log-log I took:
log(y) = a + b*log(x)
and solved: y = 10^a * x^b  (this is correct right?)

**Edit: thanks for pointing out that its ln.
I actually already tried y = e^a * x^b and it still doesn't give me the right equation.
The problem isn't solved yet.**

However, if I use the coefficients the model gives me, it doesn't match the fitted line.
How do I get the right line equation? I suspect it has something to do with the exp function but I don't know how to solve it.

```
#Output model
Call:
lm(formula = log(Outputs3$MaxVel3SD) ~ log(Outputs3$Mu))

Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-0.056629 -0.012581  0.007052  0.013824  0.040585 

Coefficients:
                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)       3.40280    0.01013  335.85  < 2e-16 ***
log(Outputs3$Mu) -0.16178    0.00916  -17.66 1.14e-13 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.02346 on 20 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9397,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9367 
F-statistic: 311.9 on 1 and 20 DF,  p-value: 1.143e-13
```

```
#Data
Mu <- c(0.197, 0.198, 0.199, 0.200, 0.210, 0.220, 0.230, 0.240, 0.250, 0.300, 0.350, 0.400, 0.450, 0.500, 0.550, 0.600, 0.650, 0.700, 0.750, 0.800, 0.850, 0.900)
MaxVel3SD <- c(39.23885, 39.32653, 39.30562, 39.25953, 39.16271, 39.24858, 38.79653, 38.31969, 37.56702, 35.99848, 33.65009, 33.77764, 32.71771, 33.25826, 32.76474, 33.10656, 32.86643, 31.35003, 31.06606, 31.77586, 31.20700, 31.83073)

df <- data.frame(Mu,MaxVel3SD)
```

I hope this is enough information.
Summary: How do I find the line equation?

Comment: "this is correct right?" No, it isn't. The R function `log` is the natural logarithm (base e) and not the decadic logarithm (base 10). It should be $e^a$ instead of $10^a$.

Comment: I figured that out, but it still does not give me the right equation for the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation of the line on the original scale is
$$
e^{\log(y)}=e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1\log(x)}=y=e^{\beta_{0}}x^{\beta_{1}}=e^{3.4028}x^{-0.16178}
$$

To show this, plot the above equation and the exponentiated predictions together:

```
Mu <- c(0.197, 0.198, 0.199, 0.200, 0.210, 0.220, 0.230, 0.240, 0.250, 0.300, 0.350, 0.400, 0.450, 0.500, 0.550, 0.600, 0.650, 0.700, 0.750, 0.800, 0.850, 0.900)
MaxVel3SD <- c(39.23885, 39.32653, 39.30562, 39.25953, 39.16271, 39.24858, 38.79653, 38.31969, 37.56702, 35.99848, 33.65009, 33.77764, 32.71771, 33.25826, 32.76474, 33.10656, 32.86643, 31.35003, 31.06606, 31.77586, 31.20700, 31.83073)

df <- data.frame(Mu, MaxVel3SD)

modelMV <- lm(log(MaxVel3SD) ~ log(Mu), data = df)
hmMV <- exp(predict(modelMV, data.frame(Mu = df$Mu)))

plot(MaxVel3SD ~ Mu, data = df, las = 1, ylim = c(30, 40))
lines(df$Mu, hmMV, lwd=2, lty = 2, type = "l")
f <- function(x, beta) { exp(beta[1])*x^(beta[2]) }
curve(f(x, beta = coef(modelMV)), from = 0.2, to = 0.9, col = "red", add = TRUE, lty = 3)
legend("topright", c("Predict", "Equation"), lty = c(2, 3), col = c("black", "red"), bty = "n")
```

[image: Equation]

The lines are identical.

Comment: Great! Thanks Serdash! For some reason it was not working for me. Very clear :D